# How to compile to SDL2 application to Windows from Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, mingw, sdl

So recently I downloaded the Linux Subsystem on Windows 10, with Ubuntu.

I can compile an SDL2 app to Linux with the `g++` command but whenever I try doing it with `i686-w64-mingw32-g++` this command, I get an error saying `main.cpp:5:9: fatal error: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory`.

The command I'm using is `i686-w64-mingw32-g++ main.cpp -w -lSDL2 -o main.exe`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlZmQ.jpg

Anyone knows how to fix this? :(

**[EDIT]**

So now I've tried specifying the directory of the necesary files with this command: `g++  main.cpp -I/usr/include/SDL -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -w -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -lSDL2 -o main`

which worked but when I use it with mingw it doesn't `i686-w64-mingw32-g++  main.cpp -I/usr/include/SDL -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -w -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -lSDL2 -o main`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfCRt.jpg

Comment: don't you need to specify the path to the `.h` files, i.e. `-I /path/to/SDL2` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the path to SDL's include directory on the command line.  However, you need to include the path to the *downloaded* SDL for mingw32, not /usr/include/SDL2.  The difference is the headers in /usr/include/SDL2 are for Linux and libs in /usr/lib are also for Linux, but you need to link to the Windows libraries.

What I usually do is download the development libraries for Mingw32 and put them directly into my project directory.  Then all you need to do is add **-ISDL2-2.0.8/i686-w64-mingw32/include -LSDL2-2.0.8/i686-w64-mingw32/lib** to your command line and it will be able to find the headers and libraries it needs.  Finally, make sure you copy **SDL2-2.0.8/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/SDL2.dll** to your executable directory in the Makefile.

Also, remember to link SDLmain as well.  It handles creating a WinMain for you and all that, and then calls your main function.